# Heading background with border matching parent element's border

Tags: css

I need the heading to have top rounded border matching with the parent's one.
I am using bootstrap 3, so using native CSS's flex .

```css
#steps
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding:10px;
    border: 1px solid red;    
}
#steps > div
{
    text-align: center;    
    background-color: #00ACA0;    
    border-bottom:1px solid #00ACA0;
    border-left:1px solid #00ACA0;
    border-right:1px solid #00ACA0;
    border-top:1px solid #00ACA0;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width:100px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;    
}
#steps > div > h4
{
    text-align: center;
    color:white;    
    background-color: #00ACA0;
    /*
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    */
}
#steps > div
{
    background-color: white;
}
#steps > div:nth-child(5)
{
    color: white;
    background-color: #00ACA0;                            
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="steps">
    <div>
        <h4 class="p-1">Heading 1</h4>
        <div class="p-1">Content 1</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h4 class="p-1">Heading 2</h4>
        <div class="p-1">Content 2</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h4 class="p-1">Heading 3</h4>
        <div class="p-1">Content 3</div>
    </div>                                        
    <div>
        <h4 class="p-1">Heading 4</h4>
        <div class="p-1">Content 4 - Long Content</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h4 class="p-1">Final Heading 5</h4>
        <div class="p-1">Final Content</div>
    </div>                                        
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS properties:

```
#steps > div > h4
{
    text-align: center;
    color:white;    
    background-color: #00ACA0;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;    // uncommented
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;   // uncommented
    padding-top: 10px;               // new
    margin-top: 0;                   // new
}
```

Comment: There's a slight rendering issue with Chrome, not FireFox - https://imgur.com/a/RgSS3Nq

Comment: I do not see the same in Chrome, does this work for you or have the same issue? - https://jsfiddle.net/mgLjnpsr/

Comment: Yes, there's still some rendering issue in Chrome 88 Windows 10 Pro - https://imgur.com/a/is00lPm - first 3 DIV's have a left white line while the 4th DIV has a right white line.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 88 MacOS 11.2. I'm not sure what's causing the rendering issues but you could try playing with the padding/margin or border sizes. Hopefully someone with a Windows machine can help!

Comment: There should be a way to solve this by giving background-color: #00ACA0;  to `#steps > div` and give background-color: white to `#steps > div > div` - problem with this is that the inner div doesnt expand to the height 100%